# Select info from openquery table where row has max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select Kode_AK, 
       Nama,
       Tgl_insert as dateTime_entry 
  from openquery([ARMS], 'select * from KEANGGOTAAN.dbo.LOG_NAMA')
```

It wil product result:

```
Kode_AK| Nama   |   dateTime_entry
AA     |Aperdi  |   11/29/2002 0:09
AB     |Lumbung |   11/29/2002 0:10
AC     |Trisula |   11/29/2002 0:11
AD     |Kapita  |   11/29/2002 0:12
AD     |OSO     |   3/30/2011 11:38
AE     |Jasereh |   11/29/2002 09:23
AE     |Paribas |   11/29/2002 09:24
AE     |Tradeez |   11/29/2002 09:25
AE     |Finansa |   11/29/2002 09:26
AF     |Harita  |   11/29/2002 09:27
```

As you can see there is a row which it have the same Kode_AK but different datetime. For the same Kode_AK, I want to select only the data which it is the last dateTime_entry. So the result will be like this:

```
Kode_AK| Nama   |   dateTime_entry
AA     |Aperdi  |   11/29/2002 0:09
AB     |Lumbung |   11/29/2002 0:10
AC     |Trisula |   11/29/2002 0:11
AD     |OSO     |   3/30/2011 11:38
AE     |Harita  |   11/29/2002 09:26
AF     |Harita  |   11/29/2002 09:27
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Should the Nama for AE be Finansa in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select Kode_AK, dateTime_entry, Nama
 from (
 select 
 ROW_NUMBER () over ( partition by Kode_AK order by dateTime_entry desc ) rn,
 Kode_AK, Nama,
 dateTime_Entry
 from 
 LOG_NAMA ) A 
 where rn = 1
```

The above query assigns numbers to each group of Kode_AK starting from 1 in desc way. After that we select only these records with 1 .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it may help you.

```
SELECT Kode_AK, Nama, Tgl_insert as dateTime_entry 
FROM OPENQUERY([ARMS],
'SELECT * FROM KEANGGOTAAN.dbo.LOG_NAMA t
JOIN
(
    SELECT Kode_AK, MAX(Tgl_insert)  
    FROM KEANGGOTAAN.dbo.LOG_NAMA
    GROUP BY Kode_AK
)AS temp 
ON temp.Kode_AK = t.Kode_AK AND temp.Tgl_insert = t.Tgl_insert')
```

Comment: Note that if for certain `Kode_AK` there can exist multiple `Tgl_insert`'s with the same value, and that value happens to be the maximum, that this version will return multiple rows for that `Kode_AK`. The only way to ensure only one row is returned per `Kode_AK` is to use dcieslak's version.